# pandas row operation to keep only the right most non zero value per row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How to keep the right most number in each row in a dataframe?

```
a = [[1, 2, 0], [1, 3, 0], [1, 0, 0]]
df = pd.DataFrame(a, columns=['col1','col2','col3'])
df

      col1  col2    col3
row0    1   2       NaN
row1    1   3       0
row2    1   0       0
```

Then after transformation

```
      col1  col2    col3
row0    0   2       0
row1    0   3       0
row2    1   0       0
```

Based on the suggestion by [divakar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3293881/divakar) I've come up with the following:

```
import pandas as pd
a = [[1, 2, 0, None], 
     [1, 3, 0,0], 
     [1, 0, 0,0], 
     [1, 0, 0,0], 
     [1, 0, 0,0], 
     [0, 0, 0,1]]

df = pd.DataFrame(a, columns=['col1','col2','col3','col4'])
df.fillna(value=0,inplace=True) # Get rid of non numeric items
a

[[1, 2, 0, None],
 [1, 3, 0, 0],
 [1, 0, 0, 0],
 [1, 0, 0, 0],
 [1, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 1]]

# Return index of first occurrence of maximum over requested axis.
# 0 or 'index' for row-wise, 1 or 'columns' for column-wise
df.idxmax(1)

0    col2
1    col2
2    col1
3    col1
4    col1
5    col4
dtype: object
```

Create a matrix to mask values

```
numberOfRows = df.shape[0]
df_mask= pd.DataFrame(columns=df.columns,index=np.arange(0, numberOfRows))
df_test.fillna(value=0,inplace=True) # Get rid of non numeric items

# Add mask entries
for row,col in enumerate(df.idxmax(1)):
   df_mask.loc[row,col] = 1

df_result=df*df_mask
df_result

col1    col2    col3    col4
0   0   2   0   0.0
1   0   3   0   0.0
2   1   0   0   0.0
3   1   0   0   0.0
4   1   0   0   0.0
5   0   0   0   1.0
```

Comment: perhaps easier to do via column operations on the transpose of the df?

Comment: Shouldn't your code be `a = [[1, 2, None], [1, 3, 0], [0, 0, 0]]`? The current code doesn't seem to fit your example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a workaround that requires the use of helper functions:

```
import pandas as pd

    #Helper functions
def last_number(lst):
    if all(map(lambda x: x == 0, lst)):
        return 0
    elif lst[-1] != 0:
        return len(lst)-1
    else:
        return last_number(lst[:-1])

def fill_others(lst):
    new_lst = [0]*len(lst)
    new_lst[last_number(lst)] = lst[last_number(lst)]
    return new_lst

#Data
a = [[1, 2, 0], [1, 3, 0], [1, 0, 0]]
df = pd.DataFrame(a, columns=['col1','col2','col3'])
df.fillna(0, inplace = True)

print df

   col1  col2  col3
0     1     2     0
1     1     3     0
2     1     0     0

#Application
print df.apply(lambda x: fill_others(x.values.tolist()), axis=1)

   col1  col2  col3
0     0     2     0
1     0     3     0
2     1     0     0
```

As their names suggest, the functions get the last number in a given row and fill the other values with zeros.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Working at NumPy level, here's one vectorized approach using [`broadcasting`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) -

```
np.where(((a!=0).cumsum(1).argmax(1))[:,None] == np.arange(a.shape[1]),a,0)
```

Sample run -

```
In [7]: a # NumPy array
Out[7]: 
array([[1, 2, 0],
       [1, 3, 0],
       [1, 0, 0]])

In [8]: np.where(((a!=0).cumsum(1).argmax(1))[:,None] == np.arange(a.shape[1]),a,0)
Out[8]: 
array([[0, 2, 0],
       [0, 3, 0],
       [1, 0, 0]])
```

---

Porting it to `pandas`, we would have an implementation like so -

```
idx = (df!=0).values.cumsum(1).argmax(1)
df_out = df*(idx[:,None] == np.arange(df.shape[1]))
```

Sample run -

```
In [19]: df
Out[19]: 
   col1  col2  col3  col4
0     1     2     0   0.0
1     1     3     0   0.0
2     2     2     2   0.0
3     1     0     0   0.0
4     1     0     0   0.0
5     0     0     0   1.0

In [20]: idx = (df!=0).values.cumsum(1).argmax(1)

In [21]: df*(idx[:,None] == np.arange(df.shape[1]))
Out[21]: 
   col1  col2  col3  col4
0     0     2     0   0.0
1     0     3     0   0.0
2     0     0     2   0.0
3     1     0     0   0.0
4     1     0     0   0.0
5     0     0     0   1.0
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to broadcast approach. The pandas approach works great for a square matrix but when I add a few more rows I get a 'ValueError: Lengths must match to compare' error.

Comment: @RudigerWolf Updated that with `argmax` solution.

Comment: Thanks, @divakar but the problem with that using argmax is that if I have a row 1,1,1,1,0 then it returns the index of the first one in the row not the right most index.

Comment: @RudigerWolf Check out the edits. Missed out on using `cumsum` when porting to pandas.

Comment: @RudigerWolf Sorry, needed one last edit :) Updated.

Answer (score 1):

You can fill null values "from the left", and then take the values of the resulting last column:

```
In [49]: df.fillna(axis=0, method='bfill')['col3']
Out[49]: 
0    0.0
1    0.0
2    0.0
Name: col3, dtype: float64
```

**Full Example**

```
In [50]: a = [[1, 2, None], [1, 3, 0], [0, 0, 0]]

In [51]: df = pd.DataFrame(a, columns=['col1','col2','col3'])

In [52]: df.fillna(axis=0, method='bfill')['col3']
Out[52]: 
0    0.0
1    0.0
2    0.0
Name: col3, dtype: float64
```